Call Option, Delta and Expected Payoff
In Dynamic Hedging by N. Taleb, at pag. 283-284, there is an argument about the relationship between risk neutral evaluation of a binary call and the delta about a call.
The author states that:

Financial market impose the constraint on every security that the left integral be equal to the right integral plus the risk-neutral drift, which result in a mean of the risk-neutral drift, m
$$
\int_{-\infty}^m f(x)p(x)dx = \int_{m}^{\infty} f(x)p(x)dx + \text{risk-neutral drift}
$$
[...] The skew by increasing the potential payoff in the left integral needs to be compensated with a shift of the mean to the right to prevent markets from giving the short seller any higher expected return than the long holder.


What is being compensated? I suppose that the risk-neutral measure will give more probability to the right tail of the distribution of the asset, correct?
How is possible that the right integral is the delta of a call, as the author states at pag. 284? Or is he referring to a binary call?
What is "m"?

Note: f() is the payoff, p() the distribution of the asset that has a negative asymmetry.
Please, let me know if more details are needed. Thanks for the help.

These questions should be asked to the author.

Let’s hope someone has some insights. If not, I volunteer to write to the author :)
